# Importing rxjs in an angular2 component gives error

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular2 component, I have

```
import * as Rx from '@reactivex/rxjs';
```

The Visual Studio complaints that 'Cannot find module @reactivex/rxjs'

I see that **@reactivex\rxjs** is installed under **node_modules** under angular2. The following is the folder structure.

*node_modules\angular2\node_modules\@reactivex\rxjs*

How can I fix so I can use Rx in the component?

UPDATE:

A similar [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5540) from Github.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of alpha are you using? I am using Alpha-45 and the following works for me:
    import * as Rx from "@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx";

Comment: I'm using Alpha-46. After I installed RxJS using the *npm install @reactivex/rxjs*, then the error in the Visual Studio IDE went away. But it gives me error during the runtime. I opened a ticket in systemJS repo which you can see it [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/931).